# Filter a python table with sql data using "dynamic" sql queries

Tags: python, sql-server, pyqt5

I have an PyQt5 dialog with a table, 3 buttons (delete row, add row and filter) and 5 comboboxes, in those comboboxes I have all the items written in an external SQL databes (for example I have  customers, drivers ecc..), the user can choose an item from each combobox, afetr choosing it when the users press the filter button(the object name is 'bottonefiltra') automatically the table will be filtered based on which customer, driver ecc the user selected. Here's my code and here's where I'm stuck :

```
def __init__(self):
    super(modificaviaggi, self).__init__()
    uic.loadUi('modifica_reg.ui', self)
    bottonefiltra = self.bottone_filtra
    bottonefiltra.clicked.connect(self.filtertable)
def filtertable(self):
    self.tabella_registrazioni.clear()
    self.tabella_registrazioni.blockSignals(True)
    startdate = self.input_dal.date().toPyDate()
    enddate = self.input_al.date().toPyDate()
    farticle = self.filtro_articolo.currentText()
    fwarehouse = self.filtro_magazzino.currentText()
    fcustomer = self.filtro_cliente.currentText()
    fplate = self.filtro_targa.currentText()
    fdriver = self.filtro_autista.currentText()
```

How can I create a query that changes based on the item selected without creating 30 if statements? I'll explain it better, to do what I want I'd most likely create an if to check which combobox has an item selected like this :

```
if farticle != " " :
        if fwarehouse != " ":
            if fcustomer != " " :
                if fplate != " " :
                    if fdriver != " " :
```

then I'll execute a query where like :

```
c.execute('SELECT * FROM Viaggi WHERE DataDDT < ? AND DataDDT > ? AND Ragione_sociale = ? AND Targa = ? AND Autista = ? AND Magazzino = ? AND Articolo = ?', 
                        (fcustomer, fplate, fdriver, fwarehouse, farticle))
```

but everytime I have to write like 10-15 different queries based on the combination of which items are selected(maybe 1 combo has an item selected and third no ecc...). How can I do it without writing 20 queries and without making 20 If statements to check which combo has an item selected ?

Comment: This blog had some awesome ideas to build something like this: https://death.andgravity.com/query-builder-how

Comment: What you're trying to do is difficult because it's trying to write SQL using Python. Creating code using code is a bit tricky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possibility would be to pair each combo with a field name, then cycle through them to build both the query and the value list.

Somewhere in the `__init__` create a list with those pairs:

```py
self.comboFields = (
    (self.first_combo, 'FirstField'),
    (self.second_combo, 'SecondField'),
    ...
)
```

Then iterate through it and build the query:

```
query = 'SELECT * FROM Viaggi WHERE DataDDT < ? AND DataDDT > ?'
values = [startdate, enddate]
for combo, field in self.comboFields:
    value = combo.currentText()
    if value != ' ':
        query += ' AND {} = ?'.format(field)
        values.append(value)

c.execute(query, values)
```

Comment: It's a shame not to include the dates as well. Perhaps include the operator in the field params, and then use an isinstance check to extract the value?

Comment: @ekhumoro You're absolutely right, unfortunately the OP didn't really clarify if the dates are mandatory or not, nor how they're going to check the validity of that field (also, field and object names are not very clear - not even for me, and that's my language). From the question (and the nested ifs) it seems that they only need to change the query according to the combos, then I assumed that the dates were always included. Besides, the original query doesn't seem to include them in the value list, so I decided to just go on with the combo iteration.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that, I figured out that dates probably will always be inside the query, even if the user doesn't select them they have a default value (01-01-2000)